# Fix laptop monitor hardware flicker caused by the actual screen

Tags: display

The screen of my ASUS Notebook ROG G750JX started flickering a few days ago.

This is the situation:

1. It starts flickering after the computer has been turned on for a while. If it's been shut off for hours, then it starts after 30 - 60 min. If I just leave it turned off for a few minutes, it starts after maybe 10 min again.
2. The whole screen jumps up and down, being displaced by around 1 cm. This is when using 60 Hz update frecuency. When using higher frecuencies, the screen doesn't jump anymore - it stays firm, but shows double and highly unreadable. Still always with the same aprox. 1 cm displacement.
3. All parts of the screen flicker (Windows 10 start button, Task Manager), and in all cases (during startup, in safe mode etc).
4. I opened up the laptop, disconnected the screen cable going to the mother board and connected it again, with no difference

   5. The CPU and GPU temperatures are not related with the flickering (they've been at 45 C and screen is still flickering).
   6. When connecting an external monitor, it never flickers, while the laptop screen may be flickering at the same time.
   7. Before the flickering gets too bad, I've seen that it may be flickering differently in different apps. When looking at the desktop background, it may stop flickering, but when opening up the web browser, with a webpage with a different background, it may start flickering again. The same thing if I switch tab from one page to another with different backgrounds, the flickering sometimes may act slightly differently.

All this leads me to believe the problem is inside the actual monitor of my laptop, probably after some part inside the monitor has heated up a little.

What part of the monitor may it be that's causing this? And is it possible for me to open up the monitor and fix it, or is all of my monitor suddenly junk?

Sorry about the misaligned list. The flickering is too bad now for me to fix it because I can't see anymore and I have to shut down hahaha =).

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the GPU is good since driving an external monitor is trouble free. [ASUS G750JX replacement lcd panel](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ASUS+G750JX+replacement+lcd+panel). $80 to $110 sounds reasonable. You can also purchase [from ASUS](https://www.asus-accessories.com/laptop/g750/g750jw/g750jw-74093-55287.htm) for $130 to $150.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the temperature is not acting too much on your monitor cable.
it cause the signal to your monitor to flux, resulting in the abnormal refresh rate.

Thus it flicker, this will only appear on Windows 10. Cause it forces high refresh rates toward the screen.
If you can find a way to insulate the heat radiation; you win.

It works for me. but I hate to on the air-corn just for a laptop screen. Older machine, especially notebooks created before the release of Windows 10 do not have the capacity on the cables to withstand such pressure due to the "idiocy windows 10, when it's just an OS". Or you can always down grade it.

Comment: Can you please include a source of this information? It would be a better answer if you can provide a source for the claim that Windows 10 forces high refresh rates.